# How to retrieve a single data from SQLite Database from specific Row And Column?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to check whether the item is in the favorite or not. to show the icon favorite on a load of this activity. Please help me out, thanks in advance.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu =  menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorite_menu,menu);
        Databasehelper databasehelper = new Databasehelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= databasehelper.getReadableDatabase();
        // what should I do here ???
        return true;
    }
```

This is on click listener of the menu to update a favorite column in the database. I want to read that specific column in on create options menu.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id== R.id.favorites_button_unchecked){
            Databasehelper databasehelper = new Databasehelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Movie.COLUMN_FAVORITE,"1");
            sqLiteDatabase.update(Movie.TABLE_NAME,values,Movie.COLUMN_ID + " = " + movie.getId(),null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Movie Added to Favorite",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
            menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
        }else if(id==R.id.favorites_button_checked){
            Databasehelper databasehelper = new Databasehelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Movie.COLUMN_FAVORITE,"0");
            sqLiteDatabase.update(Movie.TABLE_NAME,values,Movie.COLUMN_ID + " = " + movie.getId(),null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Movie Removed from Favorite",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
            menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
String select_query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " where " + idorwhatever +"= " value+" ";
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(select_query,null);
    // for each item
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            // do stuff here, use cursor.getString(index)
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```